# Multiple DockerContainers WebUI's on single IP and port

Tags: docker, routes, nginx-reverse-proxy

TLDR: Looking for a routing solution to have multiple Docker Containers Port 80 following appname
e.g.

- ip-adress:80/wiki
- ip-adress:80/ticketsystem
- ip-adress:80/portainer
- ....

I'm under the impression that it should be doable using a ngninx container als a reverse proxy and routing :80/wiki to another port A assigned to the container while mapping port A to whereever the tool is hosting its WebUI

As I am new to Docker. nginx and routing, i haven't found a tutorial on how to solve this problem.
I was hoping you guys would have some experience with this and could lead me in the right direction

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The classic solution would be [`jwilder/nginx-proxy`](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy), which sets up a container running nginx and [docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen).
`docker-gen` generates reverse proxy configs for nginx and reloads nginx when containers are started and stopped.

A manual solution/tutorial for NGiNX in a docker environment is "[Using Containers to Learn Nginx Reverse Proxy](https://medium.com/@joatmon08/using-containers-to-learn-nginx-reverse-proxy-6be8ac75a757)" from [Rosemary Wang](https://twitter.com/joatmon08).